# Installed App Listview lag when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

i am getting an activity to launch all list of installed apps with app icon and name, it works good, just very laggy when scrolling through the apps. any idea to make it smooth? here are my codes, thanks.

```
public class AppListsActivity extends ListActivity{
    static final String TAG = "AppListsActivity";
    private Context self = this;
    public static boolean progressBarStatus = false;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    PackageManager pm;
    AppAdapter adapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apps_list);
        ListView lV = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lV.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

        pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null); 
        main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> launchables = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
        Collections.sort(launchables,new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); 

        adapter = new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        progressBarStatus = true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View v, int position, long id) {
        //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ResolveInfo launchable = adapter.getItem(position);
        ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
        String selectionPname = activity.applicationInfo.packageName;
        String selection = activity.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        Drawable selectionIcon = activity.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);

        editor = self.getSharedPreferences(WidgetConfigureActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        //switch (SettingsActivity.btnShortcutNo) {
        switch (WidgetConfigureActivity.btnShortcutNo) {
        case 1:
            //SettingsActivity.textTime.setText(selection);
            WidgetConfigureActivity.textTime.setText(selection);
            WidgetConfigureActivity.iconShortcutTime.setImageDrawable(selectionIcon);
            editor.putString("shortcutTimeWidget", selectionPname);         
            //editor.putString("shortcutTime", selection);
            editor.commit();
            MyWidgetProvider.mFisrtReboot = true;
            finish();
            break;
        default: 
            break;
        }       
    }
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView label;
        public ImageView icon;
    }
    private class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
        private PackageManager pm = null;
        Bitmap bmIcon;

        AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
            super(AppListsActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, apps);
            this.pm = pm;
        }       
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v==null) {
                v = newView(parent);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
                viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                v.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            bmIcon = ((BitmapDrawable)getItem(position).loadIcon(pm)).getBitmap();
            bmIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmIcon, 5, 5, true);
            bindView(position, holder);       
            return(v);
        }       
        private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
            return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false));
        }       
        private void bindView(int position, ViewHolder holder) {                                 
            holder.label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));              
            //holder.icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bmIcon);
        }
    }
```